# Using qsort function

Tags: c, function, qsort

C has an inbuilt function called qsort. I have googled how to use this function in program but I cannot fully understand it. Can somebody please explain me the variables involved in it and their specific purpose in simple words. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is it you don't understand? Try and outline your current understanding and tag which programming language `qsort` is in.

Comment: Sorry, its in c. And I dont understand how to use pointers in it. Seems scary :)

Comment: 'Built-in' is not precisely accurate…there is a standard function called `qsort()`, but it is not built in, any more than any other function in the standard library is built in.  There are numerous questions and answers on SO which illustrate how to use `qsort()` — and many more on how to implement a quick sort.  You really should explain what you're having problems with.

Comment: A minimal working example can be found on the documentation page of [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)

Answer (score 1):

**The C library function `void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))` sorts an array.**

Following is the declaration for qsort() function.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*));
```

base -- This is the pointer to the first element of the array to be sorted.

nitems -- This is the number of elements in the array pointed by base.

size -- This is the size in bytes of each element in the array.

compar -- This is the function that compares two elements.

The following example shows the usage of qsort() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: [Don't use subtraction instead of comparison in `cmpfunc()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6103650/4231385)