# Unexplainable Difference in qsort() Results Under macOS and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, clang

I had a student recently that wrote inside their comparator:

```
int comparator (const void *p, const void *q) {
    const data_t *indexp = *(data_t **)p;
    const data_t *indexq = *(data_t **)q;
    return indexp->index > indexq->index;
}
```

This worked without issue under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but failed to correctly sort when ran under macOS. Simply changing the `>` to a `-` was enough to get it functioning for both platforms.

So, what's happening here? The only thing I can think of is that the inequality means a loss of the `-1` value, but apparently Linux (or GCC) implementation of `qsort()` is unaffected?

How could this be?

**EDIT:**

I wanted to check if this was compiler specific so I compiled with clang under Ubuntu 16.04 and there is no change, it works just fine there. So, I'm thinking there is something about the actual `qsort()` implementation in libc vs. macOS (BSD libc?) that causes this to happen. I'm just really curious to know what that is!

Comment: Typically, in `qsort` call, you would do `const data_t *indexp = p;`, and call `qsort` like: `data_t p, q; ...; qsort(&p, &q, n, comparator);`.  How are you calling `qsort`?

Comment: qsort requires a [3-way comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison). C++20 is actually getting a 3-way comparison operator so you will be able to do `return indexp->index <=> indexq->index;` in that language. Not sure if C2x is also picking it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

*It shouldn't be necessary to point out that the comparator function in the OP is incorrect, and using it is Undefined Behaviour. Nonetheless, it is interesting to ask how it could ever work.*

---

Although the interface to `qsort` requires a comparator function which returns an integer, providing three possible return values, nothing obliges the `qsort` implementation to use all of that information. It might always perform the same simple two-way branch. That would be similar to the [C++ standard library `sort` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), whose comparator returns a boolean, true if the first argument is strictly less than the second argument.

Of course, your student's comparator function will never indicate that the first argument is strictly less than the second argument, which would create problems for an implementation in which the tests look something like:

```
if (*cmp(p, q) < 0) ...
```

However, if the comparator is always called as:

```
if (*cmp(p, q) > 0) ...
```

(or, equivalently, `<=`), then your student's comparator will work without problems.

Since glibc is open source, it's easy to verify, once we find the correct sort function. But all is not quite as it appears. There is a source file called `qsort.c` (in the `stdlib` directory), which implements the quicksort algorithm (*not* the introsort algorithm used by most modern `std::sort` implementations), and in that file we can see a consistent use of strict less than. For example, from the [main inner loop](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/qsort.c;h=264a06b8a924a1627b3c0fd507a3e2ca38dbc8a0;hb=HEAD#l138):

```
while ((*cmp) ((void *) left_ptr, (void *) mid, arg) < 0)
  left_ptr += size;
while ((*cmp) ((void *) mid, (void *) right_ptr, arg) < 0)
  right_ptr -= size;
```

(There are many other comparisons in the function, but they all have the same form.)

So that shouldn't work at all with your student's comparator. However, it turns out that the that is not the function usually called by `qsort`. `qsort` is actually defined in the file `msort.c`, which implements a merge sort. And the merge sort function performs less-than-or-equal-to tests. [For example:](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/msort.c#l65)

```
 if ((*cmp) (b1, b2, arg) <= 0)
```

The merge sort implementation is not in-place, which would be slower; it requires temporary memory. And that could be a problem, because `qsort` should work even if no temporary memory is available. So the actual implementation of `qsort` starts by trying to figure out whether there is enough physical memory available. (It wants physical memory, not swap space, in order to avoid swapping. Also remember that Linux does optimistic allocation so that the fact that malloc succeeds does not necessarily imply that the virtual memory addresses allocated are actually usable.) Here, it has computed the necessary temporary space required (in `size`) and used `sysconf` to ask how much physical memory the host has. (It divides this value by four so that it won't hog all of the physical memory.)

```
/* If the memory requirements are too high don't allocate memory.  */
if (size / pagesize > (size_t) phys_pages)
  {
    _quicksort (b, n, s, cmp, arg);
    return;
  }
```

So if merge sort would require too much memory, it defers to `_quicksort`, which is precisely the function I quoted from before, found in `qsort.c`.

In summary:

- The faulty comparator function will work with glibc's `qsort` implementation provided that the array to be sorted is not too big.
- If the array is too big, the sort will fail.

By contrast, the BSD `qsort` implementation does use all three comparator return values. In its [inner loop](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/qsort.c#L155), we see:

```
    while (pb <= pc && (cmp_result = CMP(thunk, pb, a)) <= 0) {
        if (cmp_result == 0) {
            swap_cnt = 1;
            swap(pa, pb);
            pa += es;
        }
        pb += es;
    }
    while (pb <= pc && (cmp_result = CMP(thunk, pc, a)) >= 0) {
        if (cmp_result == 0) {
            swap_cnt = 1;
            swap(pc, pd);
            pd -= es;
        }
        pc -= es;
    }
```

There are also calls to the comparator to find the pivot; those are all of the `<` form, so they will also produce the wrong answer. However, not all is lost; for very small vectors (less than seven elements), it uses insertion sort instead, and the insertion sort loop uses a strict greater-than comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `>` is indeed a bug.  This operation will only yield a result of 0 or 1.  Using `-` is the correct method.

The reason it worked on one but not the other is most likely because of how the list to sort was initially ordered.  When in doubt, run the code through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) on Linux.

Comment: What should I be looking for under Valgrind? The student had some unrelated "uninitialized value" issues that I fixed, but this problem persisted.

The data in the lists are completely random, though strangely (under macOS), some of the larger values are placed correctly at the end of the array (say 1000), but smaller values are all mixed up the closer you get to the start of the array.

Comment: @chrissphinx Look for any instances of reading/writing outside of memory bounds.  That points to undefined behavior.

Comment: Perhaps even better `return (indexp->index > indexq->index) - (indexp->index < indexq->index)`  (avoids possibility of overflow and handles `>, < and =`)

Comment: @chrissphinx for check your qsort use there is a automatic tool that seem to work a little, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50039077/7076153.

Comment: For small enough integer values such there is no overflow when the values are subtracted, then subtraction is OK.  When the values can be big enough, subtraction is no longer safe because of overflow.  It important that if `comparator(v1, v2)` returns a positive value, `comparator(v2, v1)` must return a negative value (or vice versa), and if one comparison returns 0, so must the other.